# Transposing 2D Arrays using SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select, unnest

Consider this table definition in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE matrices (
matrix text[][] NOT NULL
);
```

Assuming that every matrix in this table has the same dimensions, how to write a query to transpose them?

for example:

```
INSERT INTO matrices VALUES
(array[['1','2','3'],
       ['4','5','6']]),
(array[['f','e','d'],
       ['c','b','a']]);
```

after the transpose it should look like:

```
 {{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}
 {{f,c},{e,b},{d,a}}
```

Comment: Please only tag the relevant RDBMS

Comment: Why the question is MySQL-tagged?

Comment: Unnest the array until separate elements storing their positional indices for each dimention then aggregate back in needed order.

Answer (score 1):

An option uses `generate_subscripts()` to enumerate the indexes of each dimension of the array, and then two levels of aggregation.

We need a primary key column to properly rebuild each array - I assumed `id` (if you don't have such a column, we could generate it on the fly in a subquery with `row_number()`):

```
select id, array_agg(ar order by j) new_matrix
from (
    select m.id, j, array_agg(matrix[i][j] order by i) ar
    from matrices m
    cross join lateral generate_subscripts(m.matrix, 1) as s1(i)
    cross join lateral generate_subscripts(m.matrix, 2) as s2(j)
    group by m.id, j
) t
group by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b2aaa84829c25cde36d2db10e02329f5)**

Sample data:

```
id | matrix           
-: | :----------------
 1 | {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
 2 | {{f,e,d},{c,b,a}}
```

Results:

```
id | new_matrix         
-: | :------------------
 1 | {{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}
 2 | {{f,c},{e,b},{d,a}}
```